# wallet or favourite page redirecting

Tags: hooks

I am stuck in mid of a coupon website where I have to share the coupon to the user favorite page. please help me to know the process on how could I share the full coupon block to the favorite page while clicking favorite button.
mostly all the coupon website has this functionality..

[image]